# Searching option and value in the URL LARAVEL 5.2

Tags: search, laravel-5, html-select

Hello I need to put searching option and value in the URL. I know it's very basic but I have never implement the search function before ever always used the templates one but this time I need to use it. below is my code please help me.

Right now I am getting this in the link 
`list/%7Boption%7D/%7Bvalue%7D`
but I want this in the link `list/Hello/thisishelloworld` or this may be `list/option?Hello/value?thisishelloworld` but I think I can get the second option using `Get` instead of `Post` method

AND YA ITS IN LARAVEL 5.2

```
<center>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select your option from below</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="options" name="options" style="width:100%" type="checkbox">
            <option>Hello</option>
            <option>World</option>
            <option>it's Me</option>


       </select>
</div> 

<div class="col-md-4" id="value">
    <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Enter your Search below
        </div>

        <form role="form" action="/list/{option}/{value}" method="post">

            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="form-group has-success">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text" name="{{ value }}" id="value">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Search">
            </div>
         </form>
        </div>
    </div>
 </center>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function hide() {
     $("#value").hide();
$("#h").hide();
 $("#search").hide();
}

function show() {
$("#value").show();
$("#h").show();
 $("#search").show();
}

function initHandlers() {
$("#options").change(function() {
    show();
});
}

hide();
initHandlers();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Laravel 5. 2

Step 1: 
First you have to create a route.

```
Routes.php :

Route::get('/list', function(){
    // do process
})->name('search');


HTML : 
something.blade.php : 

{!! Form::open('search', ['route' => 'search', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
    <div class="form-group has-success">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text" name="search" id="value">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Search">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have the route and controller `Route::get("list/{option}/{value}, Controller@showList);`